# How to use glDrawElementsBaseVertex to draw just select individual triangles out of an VBO mesh?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

So I have a simple cube "mesh":

the 6 cube faces are 12 triangles, hence 36 "vertices" organized as 36 indices reusing 8 unique vertex positions, 6 unique vertex normals and 4  unique vertex-texcoords.

This indexed mesh is stored in a VBO/IBO pair that may have other meshes before or after it, hence base-vertex is advisable here.

Now I can render the full cube completely and correctly in a single draw call like this:

```
gl.DrawElementsBaseVertex(
    gl.TRIANGLES, gl.Sizei(36), gl.UNSIGNED_INT,
    gl.PtrOffset(nil, uintptr(myMeshIndexBufOffset)),
    gl.Int(myMeshIndexBufBaseIndex))
```

However, now I just want to draw the "first 4 triangles" (aka the "first" 2 cube-faces) -- **with 4 draw calls rather than 1 (as texture binds may happen in between)** and I'm really at a loss as to how to properly specify the *count* and *basevertex* arguments.

Well for a single triangle, I'll just *have* to assume I need to specify a count of 3. For 12 triangles I had to use 36 to successfully render the full complete cube, so 3 for a single triangle makes sense. It then picks 3 "index entries" (here defined as three uint32s per entry) from the element array. Correct?

But I just can't figure out --neither through logical reasoning nor through experimentation-- how the base-vertex is now specified here. Specifically I'll need to add my own offset to the "cube-mesh base-index" which is known. If I were to glDrawElementsBaseVertex() all individual 12 triangles separately in a loop:

```
for i := 0; i < 12; i++ {
    gl.DrawElementsBaseVertex(
        gl.TRIANGLES, gl.Sizei(3), gl.UNSIGNED_INT,
        gl.PtrOffset(nil, uintptr(myMeshIndexBufOffset)),
        (i * fooBar) + gl.Int(myMeshIndexBufBaseIndex))
}
```

then... does anyone have any insight as to what exactly *fooBar* above should represent?

It's annoying: really, in theory I was pretty sure I *did* understand the [glDrawElementsBaseVertex specification](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawElementsBaseVertex) quite completely, yet in practice nothing yields properly separately rendered select individual triangles.

Answer (score 3):

Got it... it just dawned on me the base-vertex is added to the index **value** after being taken from the element-array-buffer, rather than added as an offset to the **position** from which to read from the element array buffer... ouch. So seems I have to offset the *indices* argument rather than the *basevertex* argument, and seems I'm getting the desired results now.

Comment: well this is a dig but can you provide solution & code? Im having the same problem for past 2 days. all my draws are bad and Im running out of ideas.